# View Doesn't Display After Method Is Called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a projects.show.html page which shows a project and it's given tasks. The tasks are shown if their *completed* attribute is set to *false* (default). I have a method that converts the attribute to *true*, but when it loads the page, I get an error:

"ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ProjectsController#show
Couldn't find Project with 'id'=tasks

```
def show
        @project = Project.find(params[:id])
        @task = @project.tasks.build
    end
```

"

Here's my code:
*projects_controller*

```
   def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @task = @project.tasks.build
   end
```

*Tasks_controller*

```
def completed
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.completed = true
    @task.save
    redirect_to project_path(@project)
end
```

*Projects/show.html.erb*

```
<% if @project.tasks.size > 0 %>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Task</th>
    </tr>
    <% @project.tasks.each do |task| %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= task.notes %></td>
    <td><% if !task.completed %><%= link_to "Mark Complete", 'tasks/#{:id}/completed' %></td>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
    </table>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here `tasks/#{:id}/completed` - you put `id` as a `symbol` while you need to pass real `id`. You should use Rails routes  helper instead of `tasks/#{:id}/completed` and it will make your life easier.

- In terminal: `rails routes` or `rake routes`.
- Find the route you need
- Replace your link with something like this `link_to('My link', task_complete_path(task.id))`

If this not helps you, please reply and provide also your route definition.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, consider defining your routes like this:

```
resources :projects do 
  resources :tasks, shallow: true do 
    member do 
      patch :completed
    end
  end
end
```

(You can read more about [nesting resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) and [adding more RESTful actions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) in the docs.)

Which will give you:

```
  completed_task PATCH  /tasks/:id/completed(.:format)                 tasks#completed
   project_tasks GET    /projects/:project_id/tasks(.:format)          tasks#index
                 POST   /projects/:project_id/tasks(.:format)          tasks#create
new_project_task GET    /projects/:project_id/tasks/new(.:format)      tasks#new
       edit_task GET    /tasks/:id/edit(.:format)                      tasks#edit
            task GET    /tasks/:id(.:format)                           tasks#show
                 PATCH  /tasks/:id(.:format)                           tasks#update
                 PUT    /tasks/:id(.:format)                           tasks#update
                 DELETE /tasks/:id(.:format)                           tasks#destroy
        projects GET    /projects(.:format)                            projects#index
                 POST   /projects(.:format)                            projects#create
     new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)                        projects#new
    edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format)                   projects#edit
         project GET    /projects/:id(.:format)                        projects#show
                 PATCH  /projects/:id(.:format)                        projects#update
                 PUT    /projects/:id(.:format)                        projects#update
                 DELETE /projects/:id(.:format)                        projects#destroy
```

Notice that you now have a named path for `completed_task` that responds to the `PATCH` HTTP verb.

Then, update `app/views/projects/show.html.erb` to include:

```
<% if @project.tasks.any? %>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Task</th>
    </tr>
    <% @project.tasks.each do |task| %>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <%= task.notes %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <% unless task.completed %>
            <%= link_to "Mark Complete", completed_task_path(task), method: :patch %>
          <% end %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

It looks to me like your table is malformed, so I tried to fix it. You may need to fiddle with that.

Your TasksController#completed action is also malformed. You try to redirect to `project_path(@project)`, but you never define `@project`. It should look more like:

```
def completed
  @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  @task.update(completed: true)
  redirect_to @task.project
end
```

This, naturally, assumes you've set up your Task and Project association correctly, something like:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project 
end
```

FYI, I just cloned your projects and added this to `views/static/index.html.erb` (naturally, '1' is just a dummy ID since I don't have any records in the DB):

```
<%= link_to "Test", completed_task_path(1), method: :patch %>
```

Which gave me:

```
<a rel="nofollow" data-method="patch" href="/tasks/1/completed">Test</a>
```

When I click on it, I get:

```
Started PATCH "/tasks/1/completed" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-07-10 09:28:01 -0700
Processing by TasksController#completed as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"euLDameHwkrCCMfTsPg5Znk2Mwuh7v6/O2wZFt6zGaRJzE9F1XMgGR1Uz2oYfpeQL//v/L1QtAEo7TDqsphIFw==", "id"=>"1"}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've added your changes, but my tasks_compelted_path is a GET request and not PATCH.

<%= link_to "Mark Complete", task_completed_path(@task.id) %>

Returns: "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TasksController#update
Couldn't find Task with 'id'=:id("

Comment: Did you add `method: :patch` as I indicated?

Comment: I had that originally, unfortunately it didn't work. Getting the same error.

Comment: Your routes.rb file is incorrect. You're double defining `resources :tasks` (line 21 and 28). You're also double defining `resources :projects` (line 22 and 27).

Comment: I appreciate your help. When I remove my routes, however, I get a new error. I currently have the routes you gave me commented out, which brings me back to my initial error

Comment: See my update. I'm not sure what's wrong on your end. Perhaps you should add your `link_to` code as it currently stands, the resulting HTML, and the entire console output (beginning with `Started ...`) to your original question.

Comment: Changed the approach and went with an enumerable.

Comment: Not sure what that means. But, you may want to add an answer with your working approach so that future searches can see how you did it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, thanks @jvillian for your help.

Instead of using a method in my tasks controller to change the Task.completed attribute (originally a string), I created an enumerable (similar to a boolean in that it's binary) that can be switched from "incomplete" to "complete" whenever the method is called.

app/controllers/tasks_controller:

```
include ProjectsHelper

class TasksController < ApplicationController

def create
    t = Task.new(task_params)
    t.save
    redirect_to project_path(t.project)
end

def update
    t = Task.find(params[:id])
    if t.user == current_user
        t.update(completion_status: 'complete', completion_date: DateTime.now, completed: true)
        t.project.update(last_completed: DateTime.now)
    end
    redirect_to :back
end

def toggle_status
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])

    if @task.incomplete?
        @task.complete!
    elsif @task.complete?
        @task.incomplete!
    end

    redirect_to @task.project
  end


private

def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:user_id, :project_id, :notes)
end
```

Then for my model:

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
    enum status: [ :incomplete, :complete ]

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :project

validates :notes, presence: true

scope :completed, -> { where(completed: true) }

def self.completed
    Task.completed
end
end
```

The enum status serves as a binary option, much like a boolean. Formerly a string, I was able to change method to simply 'flip' the value of the enumerable, and write the proper controller action in my project/show:

```
<% if @project.tasks.any? %>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Task</th>
    </tr>
    <% @project.tasks.each do |task| %>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <%= task.notes %>
          <%= task.status %>
        </td>
        <td>
        <% if !task.id.nil? %>

            <%= link_to "Change Status", toggle_status_task_path(task) %>
        <% end %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>

  </table>
<% end %>
```